# MUI styled cannot pass component prop to Typography in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Using MUI with typescript and want to use `styled` from MUI as well. When passing the component prop to the styled component I get an error from the typescript sandbox below, maybe anyone knows a workaround.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lxdrj?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to manually add the 'component' prop.

From https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#complications-with-the-component-prop

```
import React from "react";
import type { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

type MyT = React.ComponentType<TypographyProps<"span", { component: "span" }>>;

const MyTypography: MyT = styled(Typography)({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px"
});

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return (
    <MyTypography component="span">Styled with styled-components API</MyTypography>
  );
}
```

Comment: nice, somehow missed it in the docs cheers mate!

Answer (score 3):

You can use generic type parameter in HOC created by `styled`:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

type ExtraProps = {
  component: React.ElementType;
};
const MyTypography = styled(Typography)<ExtraProps>({
  // ...
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This works, although it's pretty ridiculous that it's needed imo

Comment: @MarksCode see my updated answer, I have no idea why thing was so complicated before. The problem IIRC is that `component` is a very common prop and is available in all MUI components so the type definition is defined elsewhere to be more reusable which creates an unfortunate edge case.

Comment: Its still weird that you have to define that prop if it is available on the component already

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as @GitGitBoom, but without having to define a type. You can use the solution described in the [MUI Typescript Guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#complications-with-the-component-prop) where you just cast your styled component to the `typeof Typography`

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const MyTypography = styled(Typography)({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px"
}) as typeof Typography;

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return (
    <MyTypography component="span">
      Styled with styled-components API
    </MyTypography>
  );
}
```